# Is there a Stack Exchange site for UI and site design?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I need to make some difficult User Interface decision on my site and I'm looking for a community simillar to Stack Overflow, or a forum that's most known where I'd ask for advice. Could you recommend one please?

Comment: Probably http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're looking for [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/).

> #### What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> User Experience - Stack Exchange is for User Experience Designers, Information Architects, and Human Computer Interaction researchers.
>
> #### What makes a good question?
>
> We prefer questions that elicit definitive answers or solutions rather than prolonged discussions. Remember, this a Q&A site, not a discussion board.
>   More context yields better answers. Fill your question with details such as:
>
> - Description of the users' experience levels and goals
> - Mockups, screenshots, or photos of existing designs
> - Software platform, if applicable (Is it an Android app? A web form? A kiosk with a 20"×20" touch screen?)
>
> If you're familiar with other Stack Exchange sites, questions on UX tend to be a little more subjective than usual. That's okay, as long as the question follows the guidelines outlined in Good Subjective, Bad Subjective.

Comment: Also [Graphic Design.SE](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com) may be worth looking at.